# Bayesian updating with two unknown parameters

Tags: functional-analysis, bayesian

Suppose we know the following about function $f(x)$: (i) There exists $y$ so that $f(x)=\beta$ for all $x\geq y$ and (ii) $f(x)=\alpha+b x$.

We have a prior distribution on $y$ and on $\beta$.

How does Bayesian updating for one period or several periods look like? Or do you have a good reference for sth. like that?

Thank you for any ideas

Comment: If you know both of those things, then $a = \beta$ and $b = 0$ (Proof: pick $x_1 = y+1; x_2 = y + 2$, and evaluate $f$ using both conditions.) Are you sure you said what you meant to say?

Comment: Hi John, we only know the distribution of $y$ and $\beta$ but not the actual distribution. So After observing an event we have to update our beliefs. (But still I had a typo.)

Comment: "We only know the distribution...but not the actual distribution." At this point, I think you're just deliberately wasting our time by writing nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here that $f$ is a function from the reals to the reals.

There is some number, $y$, with the property that for $x \ge y$, we have $f(x) = \beta$. Letting $x_1 = y + 1$ and $x_2 = y + 2$, we get
$$
f(x_1) = \beta \\
f(x_2) = \beta.
$$

We are also told there are numbers $a$ and $b$ with $f(x) = a + bx$. Let's look at $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ given this information:

\begin{align}
\beta &= f(x_1) = a + b x_1 = a + b(y+1) \\
\beta &= f(x_2) = a + b x_2 = a + b(y+2)
\end{align}
subtracting, we get
\begin{align}
\beta - \beta &= f(x_2) - f(x_1) \\
& = a + b (y+2) - (a + b (y+1))\\
&=  b(y+2) - b(y+1) \\
&=  b 
\end{align}
whence we see that $b = 0$, from which it's easy to derive that $a = \beta$.

These are facts *from algebra*, and are completely independent of any assumptions about the distribution on $y$ or $\beta$.

As I said, I still think you're not asking what you meant to ask.

By the way, until you define an "event", the whole notion of Bayesian updating doesn't make a lot of sense. Is the event "we observe $f(c)$ for some randomly chosen $c$?" If so, with respect to what distribution is $c$ drawn? Or is an event something else?

Sigh.

Comment: Thank you John that you tried to answer my question which really had too many errors and unclarities. I will rewrite way more carefully.